# Rotating Chart symbols with ArcMap dataframe?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology, layouts, chart

I am using ArcMap 10.2 and want to represent a layer in a rotated dataframe with chart (graph) symbology. The problem is that the charts do not rotate with the dataframe:

[image: graphs do not rotate with dataframe]

I thought I could convert to graphics and rotate each chart individually, but

1. that is very tedious
2. I don't find an option to convert a layer to graphics, works for the legend but not for the actual layer symbology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same question... Try this option.
http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000002834

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Do not rotate the Data Frame. Try instead to change the 'Central Meridian' of your selected projection (right-click in the Data Frame and select properties. Switch to Projection tab and double-click the selected projection).

Comment: How would this change the rotation on the symbol? It would simply shift the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You can designation the rotation of a symbol by creating a rotation field. This is then referenced in the symbology under Layer Properties dialog box, click the Advanced button and click Rotation from the shortcut menu.

Here's a link to the [ArcGIS Tutorial](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000001v000000)

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about the rotation option. However, the "Charts" symbology option is the only one that lacks the 'Advanced' field, so this doesn't work in my case.