# Rotating charts in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology

I have just drawn a set of bar charts over a layer in ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

How can I manage rotate the charts keeping my dataframe with the same rotation?

The options offered in Symbology Display only lets you to display the chart as bar or column.

Any chance to set a rotation angle??

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the Advanced button on the layer symbology tab?  Symbol Rotation is usually in there

Comment: Hi @peter. Yes I checked but only option related to the orientation is show the chart as a bar or column, just this.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101386/rotating-chart-symbols-with-arcmap-dataframe?rq=1

Comment: Hi @Midavalo I am trying to adjust the Central Meridian. Do you know how it works? I mean Im trying different values for Central Meridian, but layout dissapears when I try to adjust the Central Meridian

Comment: That sounds like a new question, and so should be asked as one.